# cyclic quotient $\rightarrow$ simple quotient

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a module over a commutative ring with unity. Is it true that if $M$ has a cyclic quotient it also has a simple quotient (both of course non zero)?

Comment: If you believe Zorn's lemma, then every ideal is contained in a maximal ideal.

Comment: Ahhhhh, thanks! Now i feel stupid :)

Comment: If you make an answer I can accept it :)